# How can I use CURL to upload a CSV to AWS elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I got a huge CSV with millions of records. I want to upload it to aws elasticsearch to run some queries. I tried to convert the CSV to JSON format mentioned on AWS docs, the format is like this:

```
{ "index" : { "_index": "movies", "_type" : "_doc", "_id" : "2" } }
{"director": "Frankenheimer, John", "genre": ["Drama", "Mystery", "Thriller"], "year": 1962, "actor": ["Lansbury, Angela", "Sinatra, Frank", "Leigh, Janet", "Harvey, Laurence", "Silva, Henry", "Frees, Paul", "Gregory, James", "Bissell, Whit", "McGiver, John", "Parrish, Leslie", "Edwards, James", "Flowers, Bess", "Dhiegh, Khigh", "Payne, Julie", "Kleeb, Helen", "Gray, Joe", "Nalder, Reggie", "Stevens, Bert", "Masters, Michael", "Lowell, Tom"], "title": "The Manchurian Candidate"}
{ "index" : { "_index": "movies", "_type" : "_doc", "_id" : "3" } }
{"director": "Baird, Stuart", "genre": ["Action", "Crime", "Thriller"], "year": 1998, "actor": ["Downey Jr., Robert", "Jones, Tommy Lee", "Snipes, Wesley", "Pantoliano, Joe", "Jacob, Ir\u00e8ne", "Nelligan, Kate", "Roebuck, Daniel", "Malahide, Patrick", "Richardson, LaTanya", "Wood, Tom", "Kosik, Thomas", "Stellate, Nick", "Minkoff, Robert", "Brown, Spitfire", "Foster, Reese", "Spielbauer, Bruce", "Mukherji, Kevin", "Cray, Ed", "Fordham, David", "Jett, Charlie"], "title": "U.S. Marshals"}
{ "index" : { "_index": "movies", "_type" : "_doc", "_id" : "4" } }
{"director": "Ray, Nicholas", "genre": ["Drama", "Romance"], "year": 1955, "actor": ["Hopper, Dennis", "Wood, Natalie", "Dean, James", "Mineo, Sal", "Backus, Jim", "Platt, Edward", "Ray, Nicholas", "Hopper, William", "Allen, Corey", "Birch, Paul", "Hudson, Rochelle", "Doran, Ann", "Hicks, Chuck", "Leigh, Nelson", "Williams, Robert", "Wessel, Dick", "Bryar, Paul", "Sessions, Almira", "McMahon, David", "Peters Jr., House"], "title": "Rebel Without a Cause"}
```

But I was unable to do so because I could not automate this task. Is there a software to do so ?
Then I read that I can use CURL and use the following example script:

```
while read f1
do        
   curl -XPOST 'https://XXXXXXX.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243/subway_info_v1/station' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u elastic:XXXX -d "{ \"station\": \"$f1\" }"
done < NYC_Transit_Subway_Entrance_And_Exit_Data.csv
```

But the problem with this one is that it reads the CSV line by line and uploads it as it is. It does not breaks the line into columns, So it also doesn't work.
I am unable to find any DOC or tutorial which mentions the task I want to do. Can you suggest something ?

Comment: What do you mean you could not automate it? It's not hard to convert CSV to JSON. You can write a script to do that :)

Comment: This is a common use case for elasticsearch, look for "csv elasticsearch import" and you'll see a lot of tutorials and examples. Elastic has a [blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/indexing-csv-elasticsearch-ingest-node) on how to do it using an ingest node and Logstash is another tool that can easily solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can google `csv2es`. See if these links help:

1. https://pypi.org/project/csv2es/
2. https://github.com/yanxurui/csv2es
3. https://github.com/karlssonjohan/csv2es